# I tried to read a excel file in java. While reading the integer data is read as float y?

Tags: java

```
       XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows one by one
       /* Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            Row row = (Row)rowIterator.next();
            //For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Cell cell = (Cell)cellIterator.next();*/
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
          Row row = rowIterator.next();
          Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
          while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                //Check the cell type and format accordingly
          //  DataFormat format=((XSSFWorkbook) cell).createDataFormat();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");

                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
    }
```

Here am getting the output as

Id  Name    Phone
1.0 Sanjay  8220850855
2.0 Aswin   9.897654321E9
3.0 Santhosh    9.876543212E9
4.0 Nandu   9.089876565E9
5.0 Vijay   9.090906767E9

Comment: Do you want to read the integer data as int ? you can try reading it as String and then parsing it to required type

Comment: Hint: please give some feedback regarding my answer. If it helps, you could accept it; otherwise; feel free to let me know when you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you turn to the javadoc for the method [getNumericalCellValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue()) you will find: it returns **double**.

[ and just for the record: this is Java. You can't call **one and the same** method and expect that it returns an **int** for one invocation; and **double** for another invocation! That would only be possible if the method was written to return a **Number** object; then the result could be either **Integer** or **Double**. But for primitive types this isnt possible! ]

So, your problem is a misunderstanding on your end: if a cell has a "numerical" value; then that means: you can access the cell value as floating point number! There is no differentiation on that level between "int" and "floating point".

Thus: when you *know* that the first column is about integers only; well, then you have make that "implicit" understanding explicit; for example by rounding/formatting the values for the first column!

In other words: the value is what it is. You have to change the **interpretation** of that value; based on your meta knowledge regarding the data you are working with!

Finally: that javadoc even tells you in the end:

[see: *for turning this number into a string similar to that which Excel would render this number as*](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html)